# remove image placeholder on woo commerce shop archive page

Tags: hook, woocommerce

I have been getting used to hooks for adding and removing content on various woo commerce pages.

However I can't see how to remove the images for each product from the shop archive page.

I understand that removing the featured image for each product will obviously remove the image but there is an image placeholder that remains.

I need to be able to remove the image placeholder so that all that remains is the product title  etc...

Any help is much appreciated.

edit.

I managed to sort this out but prehaps not in the most effiecient way so I'll leave my findings here for improvement in case anyone else wanted to do anything similar.

Using hooks in the normal way didn't have a any effect so I edited the main woo commerce template file, which isn't a great idea, but...

Removing...

```
<?php
/**
* woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
*
* @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>
```

From content-product.php file within the plugin/woocommerce/templates folder had the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

Don't remove it, you can use **remove_action()** function. For archives, as **content-product.php** says, in functions.php you can write:

```
remove_action(
  'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail',
  10
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the way I would expect to edit the page. Unfortunately and for reasons that I don't understand this doesn't have any effect in this particular instance. 

Curiously I can remove other elements in this way without issue.

This is why I had to resort to cutting code from the file itself.

Comment: :) , so I guess you can change the number **10** and get the answer. This parameter is the priority and I think if you choose a higher number, like 50 or 70 and so on, it will work. I mean I hope so :P